# How to check auto proxy state for argument in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, arguments

I don't have much experience with shell scripting and don't fully understand passing arguments to if else statements. I want to check the state of an auto proxy, i.e. whether it is enabled or disabled. if it is enabled(has an url) i want to turn it off and vice versa. 
so far i have:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[networksetup -getautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi"] = "https://mediahint.com/default.pac"] then
networksetup -setautoproxystate "Wi-Fi" off

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
else 
networksetup -setautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi" https://mediahint.com/default.pac

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
fi
```

it's just the argument of the if statement i'm not sure on.
the statements work fine i have checked in another script.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, all is ok, except the fiest line.

You must write:

```
if [ `networksetup -getautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi"` = "https://mediahint.com/default.pac" ]; then
```

Note:

- backticks ``, that mean command subsitution;
- `;` before `then`;
- space before `]` and after `[`.